# Бесплатный api новостей об криптовалюте

Tags: api, поиск-api, криптовалюта

может кто-нибудь дать ссылку на сайт который дает в api новости об криптовалюте? Сколько уже ищу все не могу найти, на сайте есть новости, а в api нет только сами данные про криптовалюту.

Comment: Тут скорее всего надо какой-то парсер писать, вряд ли API найдешь.

Comment: Ок, попробую что-то сделать